# why /var/log/wtmp and /var/log/lastlog have read permission for other users? Is it necessary?

Tags: linux, oracle-linux

In my Linux server lastlog and wtmp files have read permission set for other users (664) . Do we really need to keep the read permission for other users or can I change it to (660 or 640) . Does it affect anything in the server like some command execution and all ?

In one of the server even though lastlog is with 000 (wtmp with 664) , Commands like last,who are working for non-root user .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the file `/var/log/wtmp`, the read and write permission for the group `utmp`  is to allow it to write the login, logout informations to the file. Changing it to `readonly` for group will affect this process.

And the read access for `others` is to read the file on executing commands like `last`, `who` which are dependent on `wtmp` log. If this read is revoked, these commands will throw Permission Denied errors unless executed by `root` or `sudo user`.

`/var/log/lastlog` is used for `lastlog` command, modifying the permissions of this file will lead to similar errors for `lastlog` command only.

Answer (score 0):

There is no private information in such files, and I find useful to find which user are logged and when they logged in my machines (active users), e.g. before to make a reboot.

I could construct the same information (less precise) looking for processes (think about `top` or `ps`). Just the IP address is not there, but possibly users can discover it anyway.